# Airflow: Indefinitely running HTTP Task with no response

Tags: http, airflow

Please help me understand on why is this http task running for long time, with no progress.

I`m running the official example on HTTP but looks like missing something here.

https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/providers-http/4.1.1/tests/system/providers/http/example_http.py

```
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_EMAIL=airflow@example.com
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER=airflow
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=example_http_operator
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=http_sensor_check
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2023-02-17T20:53:45.614721+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_TRY_NUMBER=1
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=manual__2023-02-17T20:53:45.614721+00:00
[2023-02-17, 20:53:48 UTC] {__init__.py:117} DEBUG - Preparing lineage inlets and outlets
[2023-02-17, 20:53:48 UTC] {__init__.py:155} DEBUG - inlets: [], outlets: []
[2023-02-17, 20:53:48 UTC] {http.py:122} INFO - Poking: 
[2023-02-17, 20:53:48 UTC] {base.py:73} INFO - Using connection ID 'http_default' for task execution.
[2023-02-17, 20:53:48 UTC] {http.py:150} DEBUG - Sending 'GET' to url: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/
[2023-02-17, 20:53:52 UTC] {taskinstance.py:769} DEBUG - Refreshing TaskInstance <TaskInstance: example_http_operator.http_sensor_check manual__2023-02-17T20:53:45.614721+00:00 [running]> from DB
[2023-02-17, 20:53:52 UTC] {base_job.py:240} DEBUG - [heartbeat]
[2023-02-17, 20:53:58 UTC] {taskinstance.py:769} DEBUG - Refreshing TaskInstance <TaskInstance: example_http_operator.http_sensor_check manual__2023-02-17T20:53:45.614721+00:00 [running]> from DB
[2023-02-17, 20:53:58 UTC] {base_job.py:240} DEBUG - [heartbeat]
[2023-02-17, 20:54:03 UTC] {taskinstance.py:769} DEBUG - Refreshing TaskInstance <TaskInstance: example_http_operator.http_sensor_check manual__2023-02-17T20:53:45.614721+00:00 [running]> from DB
[2023-02-17, 20:54:03 UTC] {base_job.py:240} DEBUG - [heartbeat]
[2023-02-17, 20:54:08 UTC] {taskinstance.py:769} DEBUG - Refreshing TaskInstance <TaskInstance: example_http_operator.http_sensor_check manual__2023-02-17T20:53:45.614721+00:00 [running]> from DB
[2023-02-17, 20:54:08 UTC] {base_job.py:240} DEBUG - [heartbeat]
[2023-02-17, 20:54:13 UTC] {taskinstance.py:769} DEBUG - Refreshing TaskInstance <TaskInstance: example_http_operator.http_sensor_check manual__2023-02-17T20:53:45.614721+00:00 [running]> from DB
```

Surprisingly, I`m able to test this code from CLI without any issue but having trouble run this from UI.

```
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_EMAIL=airflow@example.com
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER=airflow
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=example_http_operator
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=http_sensor_check
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2023-02-17T21:05:22.781965+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_TRY_NUMBER=1
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=__airflow_temporary_run_2023-02-17T21:05:22.781968+00:00__
[2023-02-17 16:05:23,328] {__init__.py:117} DEBUG - Preparing lineage inlets and outlets
[2023-02-17 16:05:23,328] {__init__.py:155} DEBUG - inlets: [], outlets: []
[2023-02-17 16:05:23,329] {http.py:122} INFO - Poking: 
[2023-02-17 16:05:23,332] {base.py:73} INFO - Using connection ID 'http_default' for task execution.
[2023-02-17 16:05:23,332] {http.py:150} DEBUG - Sending 'GET' to url: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/
[2023-02-17 16:05:23,335] {connectionpool.py:1003} DEBUG - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): jsonplaceholder.typicode.com:443
[2023-02-17 16:05:23,667] {connectionpool.py:456} DEBUG - https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com:443 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 None
[2023-02-17 16:05:23,669] {base.py:228} INFO - Success criteria met. Exiting.
[2023-02-17 16:05:23,669] {__init__.py:75} DEBUG - Lineage called with inlets: [], outlets: []
[2023-02-17 16:05:23,670] {taskinstance.py:1329} DEBUG - Clearing next_method and next_kwargs.
[2023-02-17 16:05:23,670] {taskinstance.py:1318} INFO - Marking task as SUCCESS. dag_id=example_http_operator, task_id=http_sensor_check, execution_date=20230217T210522, start_date=, end_date=20230217T210523
[2023-02-17 16:05:23,670] {taskinstance.py:2241} DEBUG - Task Duration set to None
[2023-02-17 16:05:23,696] {cli_action_loggers.py:83} DEBUG - Calling callbacks: []
[2023-02-17 16:05:23,696] {settings.py:407} DEBUG - Disposing DB connection pool (PID 65429)
```

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by running it from the CLI and running from the UI? What specific CLI command are you calling? How are you attempting to run this from the UI? What are the parameters of the http_conn_id?

Answer (score 0):

add a timeout because the endpoint "" is never going to answer httpbin

```py
task_http_sensor_check = HttpSensor(
    task_id="http_sensor_check",
    http_conn_id="http_default",
    endpoint="",
    request_params={},
    response_check=lambda response: "httpbin" in response.text,
    poke_interval=5,
    extra_options={"timeout":5},
    dag=dag,
)
```